# laravel how to access uploaded image by store method with symlink

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-filesystem

I'm trying to upload an image in laravel and I'm using `store` method to save it in storage.

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('public/avatar');
```

It's working fine and save the file into `storage/app/public/avatar/` directory and its path will be somethin like this:

```
public/avatar/o4C4pTNuot8dDmAjpATPn5ZJWMkbfhdKJGF5PEmw.jpg
```

And that's ok! but I have a problem with retrieving this image!
when I try this address:

```
domain.local/public/avatar/o4C4pTNuot8dDmAjpATPn5ZJWMkbfhdKJGF5PEmw.jpg
```

it shows a **404 not found** page.

Anyway! I know that, if I change `public` to `storage` in address, it will show me the image.

Is it normal? I know something is not ok, but I don't know what and why!

p.s: I used `php artisan storage:link` and created symlink before, so my address is accessible.

Comment: have you tried <img src=""> tag ?

Comment: if you have symlinked the storage path to public path, you can access the file from the public path directly. and if you serve your project without `public` in the url, then you have to omit the public part from the url to access the file. `domain.local/avatar/o4C4pTNuot8dDmAjpATPn5ZJWMkbfhdKJGF5PEmw.jpg`

Comment: @MR.VIN Yes. but it's not working.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I already tested this one too! and gues what? not working :-\
I appreciate your time and your answer, anyway :)